# Route is not identified in Laravel route

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-7, laravel-route

I have been trying to learn laravel, but for some reason my routes are not identified specially in those cases where I need to pass route parameters like id.
This is my web.php

```
Route::put('/todos/{$todo}/complete','TodoController@complete')->name('todos.complete');
Route::resource('/todos','TodoController');
```

This is from where I am calling this route

```
@foreach($todos as $todo)
    <li class="flex justify-between p2">
        @if($todo->completed)
            {{-- <p><del>{{$todo->title}}</del></p> --}}
            <p class="line-through">{{$todo->title}}</p>

        @else
        <p>{{$todo->title}}</p>
        @endif

        <div>
            <a href="{{route('todos.edit',[$todo->id])}}" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
            @if(!$todo->completed)      
        <span onclick="event.preventDefault();document.getElementById('form-complete-{{$todo->id}}').submit()" class="btn btn-danger fa fa-check px2" ></span>
        <form action="{{route('todos.complete',$todo->id)}}" id="{{'form-complete-'.$todo->id}}" method="post" style="display:none">
                @csrf
                @method('put')
               
            </form>
            @else
            <span onclick="event.preventDefault();" class="btn btn-success fa fa-check px2" ></span>
            <form action="{{route('todos.complete',$todo->id)}}" method="post" style="display:none">
                @csrf
                @method('put')

            </form>

            @endif
     
        </div>
        
    </li>   
           
    @endforeach
```

I have setup my controller as follows:

```
public function complete(Todo $todo){
    $todo->update(['completed'=>true]);
    return redirect()->back()->with('message','Todo Completed');
}
```

This is my route for this :

```
| PUT       | todos/{$todo}/complete | todos.complete | App\Http\Controllers\TodoController@complete | web
```

I had this similar issue in post route for edit where I needed to pass parameter as well. There I simply solved using a resource method. But in this case since I had to input a custom function in controller, the route is not available.
I am having a 404 not found error in:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/todos/1/complete

It has been a while since I did laravel. So I am new the basics of routing. Please help me out

Comment: Route parameters don't use `$` ... in `'/todos/{$todo}/complete'`, that should be `'/todos/{todo}/complete'`. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#route-parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```php
Route::put('/todos/{$todo}/complete','TodoController@complete')->name('todos.complete');
```

to:

```php
Route::put('/todos/{todo}/complete','TodoController@complete')->name('todos.complete');
```

Without the `$` of `{$todo}`

**See: [Route Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-parameters)**

Comment: Thanks a lot I understand now

Comment: @MaestroAshmin happy to helped you!

Comment: @MaestroAshmin don’t forget to accept / upvote an answer that suit to your question

Answer (score 1):

Route parameters are defined in the URI as `{var}` not `{$var}`:

```
'/todos/{todo}/complete'

route('todos.complete', ['todo' => $todo->id])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I understand now